# Adding components to Flex 4 app makes screen go blank?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex4

I've been adding some components to a Flex 4 app (it was originally Flex 3 but has been ported).  Some of these components make the app go blank when it loads.  I'm not even able to see the loading progress bar.  Just white.

For example, adding

```
<s:controlBarContent>
    <s:Button label="Admin" />
</s:controlBarContent>
```

To the root  tag causes this.  I also was able to make it happen when I tried setting a custom components skin from my style sheet instead of from the skinClass property.

Has anyone else run across this behavior?

Comment: That is unusual behavior.  Can you share a full running sample that makes it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the creationPolicy for the navigation container to auto or all fixed it...